# Is there an alternative to c:choose in JSF when using f:validator

Tags: jsf

I understand I cannot use `<c:choose>` within a component in a jsf page.  I am trying to see if there is an alternative.  I looked at the Tomahawk and that isn't what I really need.  I am trying to validate negative and positive numbers in a column.  I want to be able to choose between the 2 validator tags that I have created.  I tried using the rendered attribute but it still doesn't work.  Below is kind of what I am looking for but it is not working like I want it to.  Does anyone have any suggestions??

Thanks in advance.

```
 <c:choose>
        <c:when test="#{entry.dataEntry.posValue}">
           <f:validator validatorId="hits.positiveNumberValidator"/>
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise test="#{entry.dataEntry.negValue}">
           <f:validator validatorId="hits.negativeNumberValidator"/>
        </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap in another validator and add them as attributes.

```
<f:validator validatorId="hits.numberValidator"/>
<f:attribute name="posValue" value="#{entry.dataEntry.posValue}" />
<f:attribute name="negValue" value="#{entry.dataEntry.negValue}" />
```

And then in the `NumberValidator`:

```
Boolean negValue = component.getAttributes().get("negValue");

if (posValue != null && posValue) {
    new PositiveNumberValidator().validate(context, component, value);
}

Boolean posValue = component.getAttributes().get("posValue");

if (negValue != null && negValue) {
    new NegativeNumberValidator().validate(context, component, value);
}
```

Note that this doesn't work when `#{entry}` is actually an iterated item like as declared in `var` attribute of `h:dataTable` or `ui:repeat`, because the `f:attribute` is tied to the JSF component, not to its output. Since the variable name `#{entry}` hints less or more that this is actually the case, here's how you could do it.

Wrap the collection in a [`DataModel`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/model/DataModel.html):

```
private DataModel entries;

public Bean() {
    entries = new ListDataModel(someDAO.list());
}

// ...
```

Use it in `h:dataTable` or `ui:repeat` as follows:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{bean.entries}" var="entry">
    <h:column>
        <h:inputText validator="#{bean.numberValidator}" />
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

And implement the validator in the `Bean` as follows:

```
public void numberValidator(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException) {
    Entry entry = (Entry) entries.getRowData();

    if (entry.isPosValue()) {
        new PositiveNumberValidator().validate(context, component, value);
    }

    if (entry.isNegValue()) {
        new NegativeNumberValidator().validate(context, component, value);
    }
}
```

*(you may want to make those validators an instance variable of the bean instead (only if they are threadsafe))*